# Teradata BTEQ : IF conditon , Validate SP compilation with runtime actual parameters & export DDL

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, teradata, ddl

BTEQ related questions - I am compiling a list of SP's via BTEQ like this

```
.compile file=sp1 ; 
.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .GOTO SQLERROR;
 compile file=sp2 ; 
.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .GOTO SQLERROR;
.logoff
 .quit

.LABEL  SQLERROR

  .logoff ;

  .quit ;
```

I have  the following Q's regarding these

- If The SP compilation fails,  the following `.IF` condition, should catch it and  rest of the file should be ignored as per what the `.LABEL` , `SQLERROR` says

   But that does not happen

  ```
  .compile file=sp1 ;
  One Error/Warning.
  Warning: 5526 Stored Procedure is not created/replaced due to error(s).
  Total elapsed time was 1 second.
  Errors reported during compilation
  `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SPL1076:E(L3), The right parenthesis in parameter declaration is missing.
  ```

  +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----

  .IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .GOTO SQLERROR;
  +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
  .compile file=sp2 ;

  Procedure has been replaced.
    Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Why is the `IF` not working out ?

- The stored procedure replaces a view. The entire `replace stored proc` statement is generated via `show` that is exported . I will come to that later. Inside the SP the code is something like this

  ```
  REPLACE PROCEDURE "DB"."TB"
  (IN L_N2 VARCHAR(500),
  IN L_N1 VARCHAR(500)
  )
  BEGIN
  ```

  DECLARE returncode INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE mystat VARCHAR(60000);

  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
  SET RETURNCODE=1/0;
  END
  SET mystat='REPLACE VIEW '||L_N2||'.TBname ( VCol1,Vcol2) 
  As sel   col1,col2
  From '||L_N1||'.Tbname';
  CALL  dbc.sysexecsql(mystat);

  END

Here even if  Col1, Col2 have an issue e.g. instead of Col1 I'd put Co l1  the SP will compile . Understandably the run-time outcome of the Stored Procedure Call will not be evaluated when its compiled. This leaves a situation where any kind of error in the generated `replace view` DDL cannot be detected. Is there any way I can get the `replace view` to validate at the time of SP compilation ?

- Lastly- regards exporting DDL via  BTEQ 
  there is an extra space between `DB.TB` like `"db". "tb"` now when I do the same show in SQL assistant - all is well- there's no space. I have to write another sed to del the extra space .

  The view and SP code  is very long and often on UNIX the code gets split across new lines like

```
    sel foo_
        bar, foobar,Col.
        tb from db.tb 
    foo_bar is split across multiple lines .
# std BTEQ options are used. The \n is because I am echoing  all this to file
.SET ECHOREQ OFF \n
.set width 500
.set titledashes off \n
.set format off \n
.set rtitle '' \n
.export report file="$ph" \n
 show procedure $db.$tb ; \n
.export  reset ;  \n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: BTEQ simply ignores any error/warning returned by the DBMS (don't know why). If you want to stop after any error/warning you could simply use `ACTIVITYCOUNT` instead of `ERRORCODE`:

```
.compile file=sp1 ; 
.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT > 0 THEN .GOTO SQLERROR;
```

If you want to ignore warnings I don't know a reliable way without dropping the SP first:

```
DROP PROCEDURE whatever;
.compile file=sp1 ; -- creates SP whatever
HELP PROCEDURE whatever ATTR;
.IF ERRORCODE = 5495 THEN .GOTO SQLERROR; -- 5495 = SP doesn't exist
```

Q2: There's no way to validate Dynamic SQL, it's dynamic as the name implies and unknown to a DBMS before it's actually submitted.

Q3: Whitespace around a period in a qualified name don't result in an error, `db    .    td` is happily accepted by the parser.

`foo_bar` should not be split across lines unless the line is too wide, simply increase the maximum length using `.set width 30000;`

Comment: Thanks Dieter. I bumped the width up from 500 to 9K , but didn't bump further on. Thought there'd be an obvious `.set` that I missed.